# How can we control the drop target in the library " iOS shim for HTML5 Drag and drop"?

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop

I have implementing a drag and drop functionality in my responsive web app. We are using a library https://github.com/timruffles/ios-html5-drag-drop-shim for the drag and drop in mobile.

But now we have facing an issue that element can able to drop on any area. How can we control to drop the element in to a specific area or a div ?